# Facebook PHP SDK - An active access token must be used to query information about the current user

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth, facebook-php-sdk

I have problem with Facebook PHP SDK. It always throws that exception. I tried many solutions listed here, but nothing works for me.

It seems that Facebook returns to me valid access token, because I tested it with Debug tool in dashboard of my application.

What's my scenario?

I want to post to publish simple content to user's wall by calling static function:

```
function social_publish($network, $title, $message, $link = '', $image = '') {

    global $_config;

    // Initialize Facebook SDK
    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
                'appId' => $_config['fb_app']['app_id'],
                'secret' => $_config['fb_app']['app_security_key']
            ));

    // Set data
    $attachment = array(
        'name' => $title,
        'caption' => $title,
        'message' => $message,
        'link' => $link,
        'picture' => $image,
        'actions' => array('name' => 'Test', 'link' => 'Link')
    );

    try {

        $access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken(); // returns valid access token

        $uid = $facebook->getUser(); // always return 0

        $result = $facebook->api( '/' . $_config['fb_profile'] . '/feed/', 'post', $attachment); // $_config['fb_profile'] procudes 'me' in this case

    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {

        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Just to note: I am not working on local environment.

Comment: What does the debug tool say about the access token?  If you're getting that the current user is "0" it means that you don't have a valid user token.

Comment: When I tested access token via debug tool, it just returns the name of my application.

Comment: It should give you the user id associated with the token if one exists.  You should check that the user is logged in and has given permission to your application.  Maybe try http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/ to get a valid token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solve it as asked in scope request to Facebook for authentication, as I decided to use the JavaScript SDK-and then, here's the solution:

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    if ( ! response.authResponse ) {
        FB.login(function(response) {
            // handle the response if needed
        }, {scope: 'publish_actions, publish_stream'});
    }
});
```

Thank you! :-)